# Flutter List Value Being Unintentionally Updated

Tags: list, arraylist, flutter, dart

In the code below the print for 'Second Sel Food Date' food date should match 'Initial Sel Food Date', but they don't because 'tempSelected[i].set_eatenDateTime = copyToDate.millisecondsSinceEpoch;' is updating both lists. How can I prevent foodListSelected from being updated? The initial values for foodListSelected are being passed into the class using a stream provider, if that matters.

```
List<FoodModel> tempSelected = new List();

    for (var i = 0; i < foodListSelected.length; i++) {
      tempSelected.add(foodListSelected[i]);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < tempSelected.length; i++) {

      print('Initital Sel Food Date: ' + DateFormat('E-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss').format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(foodListSelected[i].eatenDateTime)));

      DateTime eatenDateTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(tempSelected[i].eatenDateTime);
      DateTime copyToDate = DateTime(picked.year, picked.month, picked.day, eatenDateTime.hour, eatenDateTime.minute, eatenDateTime.second);

      // ISSUE!!!!!
      // This is some how setting foodListSelected[i].eatenDateTime as well.
      tempSelected[i].set_eatenDateTime = copyToDate.millisecondsSinceEpoch;


      tempSelected[i].set_selected = false;
      _createFood('eaten_food', tempSelected[i]);

    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < foodListSelected.length; i++) {
    print('Second Sel Food Date: ' + DateFormat('E-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss').format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(foodListSelected[i].eatenDateTime)));
    foodListSelected[i].set_selected = false;
    _updateEatenFood(foodListSelected[i]);

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a mutator method on the same object which exists in both lists. If you want to create a new object copy for the second list, you should write a method that clones the current object, and use that in your first loop.